# How to set http proxy in JML Messenger Library

Tags: java, proxy, msn-messenger, jml

I'm developing a simple msn client using java, but i don't know how to set the http proxy parameters using the JML library.
Apparently it isn't native on the library =/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a thought: you could rely on the OS to have the proxy configured. There're a few pointers covering your various options [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html) - I was wracking my brain trying to think of ways you could wrap a Messenger object within a roll your own class to redirect all traffic to your proxy but it looks to me as though JML only exposes fairly high level stuff - I was thinking in terms of setting up a Socket client connection to your proxy & redirecting a Stream through that, if there's anywhere JML exposes its session as a Stream or anything that can be easily turned into one. Sorry I'm not more help!